# A novel about a vampire who wears a kevlar vest and survives a nuclear blast

Tags: story-identification, vampire

The novel opens with a man challenging a vampire on an island to a fight so the others can escape by raft. The vampire bites him and makes him a vampire for the good fight. Somewhere in the novel the vampire also wore a kevlar vest and survived a nuclear blast.

Comment: Do you remember any other details? Something as simple as when you read it or a guess as to when it was really can help narrow down the answers significantly. Any other plot points that may have occurred? Was it set in the West, the East, the 1600s, the 20th/21st century etc.?

Comment: Why is this getting close votes? A kevlar wearing vampire surviving a nuclear blast seems enough detail to ID the book.

Comment: @JohnRennie - I'm assuming it's because the question is relatively terse. Interesting to see who the close voters are though

Comment: Kind of reminds me of the Nathaniel Cade series by Christopher Farnsworth. There is a novella I think Deep State which has a nuclear silo, that Cade is supposed to investigate, I haven't read the book so I don't know if there is any nuclear explosion. https://www.goodreads.com/series/49835-nathaniel-cade

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but possibly [Monastery](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2159174) by Patrick Whalen. It was published in 1988 if that helps (you don't say when you read the book).

[image: Monastery]

> On Chinook Island an ancient abbey stands guard over an unholy secret. Long ago, two priests vowed to silence the evil entombed below. But now, the guardians are gone--and once again, the people of Chinook Island are stalked by the undead, seeking to feast on human blood!

I cannot find a copy of the book, but the reviews describe the plot as an ex military man fighting a vampire on an island:

> Monastery is the story of two basically unkillable folks, a hit man named Braille and an Ancient named Gregory.

and one of the reviews mentions nuclear radiation is involved:

> Isolated island, vampires start to kill, ex POW turned killer (!) fights vampires. By the way those vampires face another enemy: radiation from a nuclear power plant.